# Standalone Barcode Reader that checks against file

Tags: microcontroller, barcode

What I'm looking for is a standalone barcode reader device that checks a barcode against a list of numbers stored on the device and returns the status (valid/not valid/...) associated with the specific code.

Is there any available device that does this or will i have to make something myself with a microprocessor, sd card reader / storage addon and barcode scanning engine?

Comment: The first half of your question is a shopping question, and those are off-topic here. We'd love to answer the other part, about DIY, though.

Comment: By the way, how many different item barcodes do you need to store, and must they be shared with other scanners, or a PC?

Comment: You could do this with most any smartphone, though camera-based barcode reading tends to be slower than dedicated hardware.

Comment: Sorry about the shopping question. I think I could do that DIY. The device should store anywhere from 100 to maybe 10000 barcodes, all with a length of 12 digits. It shouldn't share the list with any other device. I also thought of smartphones, the thing is i want something very simple an foolproof

Comment: Basically you need a reader, a small programmable computer with SD card or similar storage, a power supply, and a user interface.   A lot will depend on what you are comfortable with, your feelings on user interface, and the power requirements of the scanner device you choose.  Of course such complete products already exist - delivery companies for example issue them to their drivers - scan the package, capture a signature, upload at some point.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is right, however computer isn't the correct term, an 8bit microcontroller will make due, (I know an MCU or better is what you mean.) And if all you need is valid/invalid you could use LEDs. Then you would need to load the list of codes onto the unit from a computer via usb, etc.

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie "computer" encompasses all of the above.  For an application like this, trying to squeeze into an 8-bit device may be unwise unless one is already very comfortable with that chip.  32 bit ARM cores often cost less than the high-end 8-bit devices, and once you start dealing with a file system on an SD card, having a bit more RAM to work with can be beneficial.  Processor cost is just not going to be a driver in a project like this anyway - ease of developing everything needed will be, and not being squeezed will help with that.

Answer (score 1):

The Motorola 2090 comes with a couple of basic inventory applications that are close. The source for them is provided as part of their VS2008 SDK, and rolling your own with more specific requirements using VB.NET, C# or whatever, is pretty straightforward.

All of the handhelds we've used over the past 10+ years had SDKs available that provided everything from basic access to on-board scanners and radios right up to full blown IDEs and dev environments. If you can handle VB, then you can write code for any handheld.